# Flink fails to load ProducerRecord class with LinkageError at runtime

Tags: scala, apache-flink

Running Flink 1.9.0 with Scala 2.12 and attempting to publish data to Kafka using the [`flink-connector-kafka`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/connectors/kafka.html), everything works fine when debugging locally. Once I submit the job to the cluster, I get the following `java.lang.LinkageError` at runtime which fails to run the job:

```scala
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/apache/flink/util/ChildFirstClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ChildFirstClassLoader.loadClass(ChildFirstClassLoader.java:66)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2128)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getPrivateMethod(ObjectStreamClass.java:1629)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1700(ObjectStreamClass.java:79)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$3.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:520)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$3.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:494)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:494)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:391)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:681)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1885)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:561)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.readObject(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:1202)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor358.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2178)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:576)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:562)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:550)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.readObjectFromConfig(InstantiationUtil.java:511)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.getStreamOperatorFactory(StreamConfig.java:235)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createChainedOperator(OperatorChain.java:427)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createOutputCollector(OperatorChain.java:354)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createChainedOperator(OperatorChain.java:418)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createOutputCollector(OperatorChain.java:354)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createChainedOperator(OperatorChain.java:418)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createOutputCollector(OperatorChain.java:354)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createChainedOperator(OperatorChain.java:418)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createOutputCollector(OperatorChain.java:354)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createChainedOperator(OperatorChain.java:418)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createOutputCollector(OperatorChain.java:354)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createChainedOperator(OperatorChain.java:418)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createOutputCollector(OperatorChain.java:354)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createChainedOperator(OperatorChain.java:418)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createOutputCollector(OperatorChain.java:354)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createChainedOperator(OperatorChain.java:418)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createOutputCollector(OperatorChain.java:354)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.<init>(OperatorChain.java:144)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:705)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:530)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

When looking at the loaded classes with `-verbose:class`, I see the class is being loaded several times:

```
taskmanager [Loaded org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord from file:/tmp/blobStore-8cf95113-e767-4073-9b1b-e579d46c0283/job_f0c3db8b84dd38e83f92ecf1bc61b698/blob_p-c327eb8f4333a638b2b7049049368f23254aeb9c-03045e6d6a9c8f3c7dacdded8cb97d6e]
taskmanager [Loaded org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord from file:/tmp/blobStore-8cf95113-e767-4073-9b1b-e579d46c0283/job_f0c3db8b84dd38e83f92ecf1bc61b698/blob_p-c327eb8f4333a638b2b7049049368f23254aeb9c-03045e6d6a9c8f3c7dacdded8cb97d6e]
```

Where the class is being loaded from the same Uber-JAR that I submit to Flink. Moreover, there are no multiple transitive dependencies loading `ProducerRecord`, my JAR is the only supplier of that dependency.

`build.sbt`:

```
lazy val flinkVersion = "1.9.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.flink"                 %% "flink-table-planner"              % flinkVersion,
    "org.apache.flink"                 %% "flink-table-api-scala-bridge"     % flinkVersion,
    "org.apache.flink"                 % "flink-s3-fs-hadoop"                % flinkVersion,
    "org.apache.flink"                 %% "flink-container"                  % flinkVersion,
    "org.apache.flink"                 %% "flink-connector-kafka"            % flinkVersion,
    "org.apache.flink"                 %% "flink-scala"                      % flinkVersion % "provided",
    "org.apache.flink"                 %% "flink-streaming-scala"            % flinkVersion % "provided",
    "org.apache.flink"                 % "flink-json"                        % flinkVersion % "provided",
    "org.apache.flink"                 % "flink-avro"                        % flinkVersion % "provided",
    "org.apache.flink"                 %% "flink-parquet"                    % flinkVersion % "provided",
    "org.apache.flink"                 %% "flink-runtime-web"                % flinkVersion % "provided",
    "org.apache.flink"                 %% "flink-cep"                        % flinkVersion
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an unknown reason, setting the `classloader.resolve-order` property to `parent-first` as mentioned in the [Apache Flink mailing list](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flink-user/201906.mbox/%3C38384427.41e9.16b878d098f.Coremail.barley_ss@163.com%3E) resolves the issue. I am still baffled as to *why* it works, as there should be no dependency clashes between the child and parent classloader loading different versions of this dependency (as it is not provided out of the box with the `flink-dist` I am using).

In the Flink documentation under ["Debugging Classloading"](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/monitoring/debugging_classloading.html), there's a [section which talks about this parent-child relationship](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/monitoring/debugging_classloading.html#inverted-class-loading-and-classloader-resolution-order):

> In setups where dynamic classloading is involved (plugin components,
> Flink jobs in session setups), there is a hierarchy of typically two
> ClassLoaders: (1) Java’s application classloader, which has all
> classes in the classpath, and (2) the dynamic plugin/user code
> classloader. for loading classes from the plugin or the user-code
> jar(s). The dynamic ClassLoader has the application classloader as its
> parent.
>
> By default, Flink inverts classloading order, meaning it looks into
> the dynamic classloader first, and only looks into the parent
> (application classloader) if the class is not part of the dynamically
> loaded code.
>
> The benefit of inverted classloading is that plugins and jobs can use
> different library versions than Flink’s core itself, which is very
> useful when the different versions of the libraries are not
> compatible. The mechanism helps to avoid the common dependency
> conflict errors like IllegalAccessError or NoSuchMethodError.
> Different parts of the code simply have separate copies of the classes
> (Flink’s core or one of its dependencies can use a different copy than
> the user code or plugin code). In most cases, this works well and no
> additional configuration from the user is needed.

I have yet to understand why loading `ProducerRecord` happens more than once, or what this "different type" in the exception message refers to (greping on the result of `-verbose:class` yielded only a single path for `ProducerRecord`).